# SQL Server Subquery for 2 Columns Optimal

Tags: sql-server, join, foreign-keys

I have a parent table with two foreign key references to a child table. I am trying to come up with optimal TSQL (SQL Server 2008) that will "pivot" the child column into a row. The table structure and needed result set structure are below. What is the best way to make this work?

Thanks.

```
set nocount on
declare @parent table ( parentid int , parentword varchar(3) , childid int , childotherid int )
insert into @parent values ( 0 , 'a' , 1 , 3 )
insert into @parent values ( 1 , 'b' , 2 , 4 )

declare @child table ( childid int , childword varchar(3) )
insert into @child values ( 1 , 'ppp' )
insert into @child values ( 2 , 'qqq' )
insert into @child values ( 3 , 'rrr' )
insert into @child values ( 4 , 'sss' )


needed result set
a       ppp     rrr
b       qqq     sss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not pivoting.Join two times the child table with the parent table.See I have used the left join.If none of childid columns in parent tables are not null.Then you could use the inner join as well.

```
select p.parentword,c1.childword,c2.childword from @parent p
left join @child c1
on p.childid = c1.childid
left join @child c2
on p.childotherid = c2.childid
```

Comment: I am going to ask a question that I think is not specific enough, but "is a left join faster than an inner join because i always want p.parentword to show even if childwor is null"?

Comment: Then you need left join and you should use that.inner join and left join are not equivalent logically so comparing their performance doesnt make much sense to me.However, in case of inner join optimizer has more choices of plans than left join and thus could generate the better plan.But it totally depends on the data and condition used in join.But I wouldnt worry about that because inner join wont give me the output which i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using
     select p.parentword,c.childword,c1.childword as as childotherword 
     from @parent p
     inner join @child c on p.childid = c.childid
     inner join @child c1 on p.childotherid = c1.childid